Is it still illegal to compare things to the Holocaust if they actually are?
In Germany it is broadly illegal to compare things to the Holocaust. It's seen as a form of Holocaust denial by trivialization.
Would this still be the case if the other thing actually was like the Holocaust? That is, if a dictator systematically killed 6 million people for their race or religion.

The details of the Holocause denial law are at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_Holocaust_denial#Germany I don't see anything specifically about comparing things the Holocaust.

I suspect this is an interpretation of "downplays an act" committed by the Nazis. But if your comparison doesn't actually downplay it, then this presumably doesn't apply.

For a guy who said he wasn't going to contribute to SE anymore "due to antisemitism", you're sure doing a lot of contributing.


In Germany it is broadly illegal to compare things to the Holocaust.

No, it's not. Historians compare and contrast the Holocaust in their research all the time. With context and scientific method.
It is forbidden to downplay or flat out deny it. Or disparage any victim or survivor. Since it is such a horrible part of history, any comparison by a random amateur or person with a right wing agenda will probably be seen as downplaying it, because any comparison that hints at equality with other crimes is in effect downplaying it.
For example comparing the current day Gaza crisis, as horrible as it is, to the Holocaust cannot end up anything but downplaying the Holocaust. Unless you want a long list of things that are better in Gaza today. Which certainly is not a productive thing to do to help and not the intention of anyone drawing that comparison.
The legal basis for this is "§ 130 Volksverhetzung" part 3:

(3) Mit Freiheitsstrafe bis zu fünf Jahren oder mit Geldstrafe wird bestraft, wer eine unter der Herrschaft des Nationalsozialismus begangene Handlung der in § 6 Abs. 1 des Völkerstrafgesetzbuches bezeichneten Art in einer Weise, die geeignet ist, den öffentlichen Frieden zu stören, öffentlich oder in einer Versammlung billigt, leugnet oder verharmlost.

Translation:

(3) A custodial sentence not exceeding five years or a monetary penalty shall be imposed on anyone who publicly or in an assembly condones, denies or plays down an act of the kind described in Section 6 (1) of the International Criminal Code committed under the rule of National Socialism in a manner that is likely to disturb the public peace.

But there is no shortage of books comparing the Holocaust to other historic events, it's called a history book and it's both popular and very much allowed. But you should better be a reasonably good historian, because the law does not shield you from committing such crimes unintentionally or because you lacked knowledge.

Examples of history books that compare the Holocaust to other genocides: Just about any that start to detail the methods and evens used in such, which is whole libraries full.

This is one restriction of free speech that I wish the US had.  Anytime someone says something that another doesn't like they are labeled "Nazi".
